# emulator-5554 offline

Tags: command-line, android

How can I get the emulator back online?

I ran push emulator-5554 /file path/ /sdcard/ while the emulator was online, then did adb devices and the emulator was offline and did not receive the file after refreshing.

I have tried:
1. adb kill-server and adb start-server 
2. I tried killing the process id of other emulators
3. I tried pushing to one emulator and pushing to an array of emulators.
I want multiple emulators to use the same sdcard and run at the same time.

Please help